# Last nonzero digit of a factorial

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to determine the last nonzero digit of a factorial.

I tried to solve it using division: Dividing the number by 10 or multiples thereof.

```
Ex : 7! = 5040 => 4
```

So I divide 5040 by 10 and get 4 as result.

But, let us say, we should use the number 7 in the logic instead of value of the factorial (5040).

Please let me know how can I do it?

Comment: Think of this: - How do you get a zero at the end of some multiplication? Remove them and multiply the rest number to get the last non-zero digit.

Comment: How do you handle multiples of 5?

Comment: Is this a Project Euler problem? I feel like I've solved this before, but the solution is buried in my big folder of PE code.

Comment: @Kevin I have been asked this one in interview and i replied by dividing with ten or multiples of the same .. The panel has asked assume you were given a number which factorial value cannot be hold in any java datatypes ..

Answer (score 13):

1. Compute the prime decomposition of n! as follows:

   - for each prime `p` <= `n`, the exponent of p is

      [image]
2. Subtract the exponent of `5` from the exponent of `2` and discard all the fives from the prime decomposition.
3. Multiply the remaining prime decomposition modulo 10. Note that when doing this, you can use the following equivalence: [image] (for i ≥ 0). The individual products can also be done mod 10 if necessary.

---

I used a bit of spare time to implement this solution in bash. (bash? well, why not?):

```
last_nonzero () { 
    local n=$1
    local d=$(power_mod_10 3 $(count_factors $n 3))
    d=$((d * $(power_mod_10 2 $(($(count_factors $n 2)
                               - $(count_factors $n 5))))))
    for p in $(primes 7 $n)
    do
        d=$((d * $(power_mod_10 $p $(count_factors $n $p)) % 10))
    done
    echo $d
}

count_factors () { 
    local n=$1 p=$2
    local d=$((n/p))
    local q=$d
    while ((q >= p)); do
        q=$((q/p)) d=$((d+q))
    done
    echo $d
}

power_mod_10 () { 
    local mods=..........0161000101012300070901490009010187000309
    local p=$(($1%10)) exp=$(($2%4+1))
    echo ${mods:$exp$p:1}
}
```

Yes, the last one is a hack.

Also: There is an even better recursive solution. Search http://math.stackexchange.com, or even google.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: that's step 2, which removes all of the powers of 10, leaving the remaining powers of 2. Since what remains has no powers of 5, it's safe to simply do the product mod 10.

Comment: @phant0m: how do you insert mathML into an answer?

Comment: You can't, you have to use an [online editor such as this one](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and include it as a picture.

Comment: I believe the explanation (part 1) is too thick for me, but there's perhaps another way to think it: multiplying by 5 means multiplying by 10 and dividing by 2. Also the number of powers of two is always larger than the number of powers of 5. Thus for every occurance of powers of 5, one can as well _not_ multiply by a power of two.

Comment: @Aki That's exactly what 2) does. --- rici: SO considers MathJax and similar things to be [too big a dependency](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60023/164313).

Comment: I didn't get #1; but #2 & #3 can be embedded to the iterative approach.

Comment: 1) Counts how many numbers with a factor of `p^i` are between 1 and `n` (the upper bound could actually be lowered to the `p-th root of n`). Let's consider the example `n = 15, p = 3`: The goal is to find out how many threes there are in the factorization of `15!`. With the division `15/3` we know, that 5 numbers must contain a factor of three. When we divide by `3*3` (`i=2`), we get how many numbers contain an *additional* three, that is one number: `9`. Thus, the amount of threes in `15!` is 6.

Comment: You could add, that you could perfom `modulo 10` repeatedly to prevent overflows.

Comment: Scrap that with the `p-th root`, I meant the logarithm -.-

Comment: Of course, while this approach is correct, it still has problems for really large n, say 1e18.

Comment: rici, Sure ;) Stating the limit of the sum is actually much nicer like that, than using a logarithm, not quite sure about the connotation of "happy" though... I didn't mean to annoy.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to keep **more than 1 number** when the next (modified) number ends with 5.

The first such location comes at 15!, when 14! = 87178291200, and 2*15=30 but
15! = 1307674368000.
Instead 12*15 = 180, which gives the correct result.

EDIT: but even adding the digits to two is not enough for a generic case, at 25! one would need 3 last digits of 24! = 936 to get the correct answer, which means that in the end this approach doesn't stand the heat.

Comment: Hoist by your own petard, I think. 25!

Comment: @rici, I was thinking the same thing. It seems like you can't say, "storing x digits are sufficient for any size factorial". If you're calculating (5^k)! or higher, I suspect you need more than k digits.

Comment: @kevin: you only need one digit, but you also need the difference between the power of 2 and the power of 5 in the prime decomposition of the factorial. (That's easy to compute from `n`, though.) The digit you keep isn't exactly the last non-zero digit, though.

Comment: For 5^5 one needs 5 digits, but does it go on forever? (for 5^3 and 5^4) 2 or 3 digits are enough... So, the question is if there are shortcuts: is it enough to track the number of powers of 5 modulo 5 perhaps?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: it's sufficient to track the difference between the number of powers of 5 and the number of powers of 2, and also keep one digit, as I hinted above. However, think outside the box! or see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Lets say D(N) denotes the last non zero digit of factorial, then

D(N)=4*D[N/5]*D(Unit digit of N)[If tens digit of N is odd]
D(N)=6*D[N/5]*D(Unit digit of N)[If tens digit of N is even]; Where [N/5] is greatest Integer Function
and 
D(1)=1 D(2)=2 D(3)=6 D(4)=4 D(5)=2 D(6)=2 D(7)=4 D(8)=2 D(9)=8

e.g. 
D(26)=6*D[26/5]*D(6)=6*D(5)*D(6)=6*2*2=4[D(5) means last non zero digit of 5!=120 which is 2, same for D(6)]
D(33)=4*D[33/5]*D(3)=4*D(6)*D(3)=4*2*6=8

Reference : http://quantomania.blogspot.in/2011/08/last-non-zero-digit-of-factorial.html

Comment: confirmed for N = 1 through 100000